# Emacs: How to show occurences across a directory

Tags: emacs

In a single buffer, I often use `M-s o` to show the occurences of a regular expression. How can I do this across the entire current directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rgrep`. I have it bound to this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'rgrep)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are three more ways to do it:

- `multi-occur` -- a multi-occur (multiple files or buffers).
- [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) search multi-command [`icicle-occur`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) (multiple files or buffers).
- `moccur`, in library [`color-moccur.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/color-moccur.el).